# Where can I find authentic references on "categorical cross entropy" and "categorical accuracy metric"?

Tags: tensorflow, python, keras, accuracy, categorical-crossentropy

My Python source code uses TensorFlow and Keras to implement a neural network.

The Keras source code uses something called "categorical cross-entropy" and "categorical accuracy metric". I have searched a lot of books on NN theory, and no one talks about these two specific terms. Yes, they talk about "cross-entropy" and "accuracy metric" but there are no mentions of "categorical ...".

**N.B.** These terms can be found only in the so-called "Hands-on" books.

Can anyone please supply me with authentic references on these two specific terminologies?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/34507/1794, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/51092/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Categorical just means that we will conduct *multiclass classification*. The output of the classifier is a binary vector. Each entry $x_i$ in the binary vector is a prediction whether or not the input is part of class $C_i$.

In that sense, categorical accuracy introduces nothing new: it is just the accuracy of a multiclass classifier. On the other hand, categorical cross-entropy refers to the ***joint entropy***: $H(X_1, X_2) = - \sum{p(x_1,x_2)\log_2p(x_1, x_2)}$, where each random variable $X_i$ expresses whether or not the input is to be classified into class $C_i$. [Kevin Murphy's](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=MxxZkEcAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=sra) book "[Probabilistic Machine Learning: An introduction](https://probml.github.io/pml-book/book1.html)" is a great source of reference for many topics of machine learning, including cross-entropy and joint entropy.

The random variables could be mutually exclusive or not, depending on the problem.

- If they are mutually exclusive, we would allow only one of the classes to have value 1 during training and use the softmax activation function.
- If they are not mutually exclusive, we would allow multiple classes to have value 1 during training and use the sigmoid activation function.

Comment: what about the categorical accuracy metric?

Comment: I edited the answer to mention categorical accuracy too. Basically, categorical accuracy is not a separate concept, so you would have a hard time finding it in literature.